# How to modify max http header size in amplify.yml build script?

Tags: node.js, next.js, http-headers, aws-amplify

I'm deploying a Next.Js project with Amplify, and I need to increase the max http header size, but not sure how to add it to the build script. This is the current script:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - env | grep -e NEXT_PUBLIC_ >> .env.production
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Basically, on my dev environment locally, I can simply run `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-http-header-size=64555 next dev`, but not sure where to add it here in the script. I tried doing `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-http-header-size=64555 npm run build` but it didn't work.